# Wildfly conditional reverse-proxy

Tags: conditional-statements, wildfly, reverse-proxy, predicate

i am using wildfly as webserver to host my REST interface written in java.
i am already able to use wildfly as reverse-proxy with the following code in standalone.xml
my question is: how to use a predicate (or a condition or something) to not use the proxy for every incoming call. eg: depending on the client or on some header paramaters.... (NOT depending on the path, this is what already works)

thx for your help!
BR Andreas

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
   <location name="/greet" handler="my-handler"/>
</host>
```

```
<handlers>
  <reverse-proxy name="my-handler">
    <host name="host1" outbound-socket-binding="remote-host1" scheme="http" enable-http2="true" instance-   id="myroute" path="/greet"/>
  </reverse-proxy>
</handlers>
```

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="remote-host1">
  <remote-destination host="domain.de" port="8080"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Comment: finally, i got it myself. if someone is interested:
<filter-ref name="myRevProxy" predicate="equals(1,1)"/>
<expression-filter name="myRevProxy" expression="reverse-proxy({'http://domain.de:8080'})"/>

Comment: it is another topic, but: still would be great to get reverse-proxy running over https from wildfly1 to wildfly2. if someone has tips, please share.